# Set Date Visible condition in LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

Set Date `Visible` condition in `LinkButton` Using ASP.NET C# Web Forms. I have a `GridView`. In `GridView` Template field using `LinkButton`. I want to match the condition `batchdate` **less than and equal to** then only `LinkButton` should visible true.

Below is my `LinkButton`'s code. I know wrote wrong visibility condition.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn_ViewCan" runat="server"
Text="View Candidates" OnClick="lnkbtn_ViewCan_Click" Visible='<%# Eval("BatchDate").ToString() <= DateTime.Now %>'  ></asp:LinkButton>
```

In database table `BatchDate` values is storing like below

```
2016-10-26 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(Eval("BatchDate").ToString()) <= DateTime.Now` ??

Comment: I did not get you. @JaydipJ

Comment: Have you tried what i said in my previous commnet

Comment: Not working your above comment. @JaydipJ

Comment: Any error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

In ASPX:

```
Visible='<%#GetVisible(Eval("BatchDate").ToString())%>'
```

And in the code behind:

```
public bool GetVisible(object value)
{
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(value) <= DateTime.Now)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Showing visible false only for every condition. @S.Akbari

Comment: I think DateTime.Today to check na. @S.Akbari

Comment: I check with DateTime.Today also not showing if today date also. @S.Akbari

Comment: Actually I have two link button if one will match the condition means visible true else visible that link button, still not getting please update once more time your answer. @S.Akbari

Comment: Ok now I got but want to know difference between DateTime.Now and DateTime.Today, because I want to display visible true only less then and equal to today date only. @S.Akbari

Comment: @mazhar124 The `DateTime.Today` is the same as `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Comment: I am not asking difference according to my situation will use Datetime.now or datetime.today. @S.Akbari

Comment: @mazhar124 Since you are using `Convert .ToDateTime(value)` you need to use `Datetime.Now` because `DateTime.Today` just return the date.

Comment: Any way thank you very much and Also you can vote my question, If you like my question and now I am updating your answer. @S.Akbari